# Why is my CSS layout behaving unexpectedly (see link)?

Tags: css, html, web-applications, responsive-design

This question is specific to a site I am building. Please see: http://www.creeksidekitchen.ca/seniors

The layout has two columns side by side at the center of the page at a total width of 850px. However, as soon as the browser window width is 1275px or less, the right column drops below the left one.

I want this to happen only when the window width drops to 850px or less - i.e. I want it to be responsive, so only if the window is too small to show both columns side by side should the columns stack.

Why does the stacking happen at 1275px instead?

I'm getting lost in my own layout and logic, I'm hoping someone looking at it from the outside can spot what's triggering the issue.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too localized, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, or in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following code that you should remove/edit in `master.css`:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 1275px) {
  .column2 {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

Please refer to the propertie definition: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear

Comment: It's certainly the offending code.  Perhaps you meant max width of 850 for that rule.  Whatever the case, it's what's breaking it for you Taneem.

Comment: Omg THAT'S IT. Thank you so much! I did mean for that rule to also vary based on the master width.